# Why can't I init after changePage?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I changePage to a page containing the code below, however the on_load function does not get called. However, when I replace the call to on_load() with alert("HELLO"); this does get called. Why oh why?

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
HI
   <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#index").live('pageinit', function() {
                on_load();
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: you might want to prepare a small http://jsfiddle.net example?

Comment: did you try adding your alert() at the beginning of on_load() to make sure it is (not) called ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the event you have to "listen" for is when the page shows and not when it initiates,

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

```
$("#index").live('pageshow', function() {
            on_load();
        });
```